# standardised random variable least square regression $X$ against $Y$, $Y$ against $X$

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, least-squares

Let $X$ and $Y$ be mean 0 and variance 1 random variables such that we choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to minimise

$$\mathbb{E}(X-\beta Y)^2$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}(Y-\alpha X)^2$$

after not so difficult derivation, I arrive at $\alpha = \mathbb{E}(XY)/\mathbb{E}X^2$ and $\beta = \mathbb{E}(XY)/\mathbb{E}Y^2$

then $\alpha = \beta$. This seems very strange, because if $y=mx$ is regression line, then surely $x = \frac{1}{m }y$. Why is that or have I calculated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ wrong?

PS: I initialised asked this on cross-validated. The answers I got from there made me want to vomit, see:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178330/standardised-random-variable-least-square-regression-x-against-y-y-agains

Comment: @NormalHuman that is a helpful comment.

Comment: I don´t see the relationship to linear regression.  Can you explain it ?

Comment: @calculus regression minimises the total squared distance between realisations of $X$ and $Y$ to and the regression line, which goes through the origin in this case. 

I could have posed the question as I have a bunch of points $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that they have mean 0 and variance 1, the question would have still made sense.

Comment: But from where do the expressions $\mathbb{E}(X-\beta Y)^2$

and $\mathbb{E}(Y-\alpha X)^2$ come from ? How do they relate to linear regression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will answer my own question. The reason the two regression lines are different is this:

The regression line of $Y$ against $X$ minimises the total squared distance of the $Y$ COORDINATES to the $y$ COORDINATES of the line, where as $X$ against $Y$ minimise the total squared distance of $X$ COORDINATES to the $x$ COORDINATES line.

The confusion I had with regards to the line should be unique comes from the mistaken assumption the regression line minimise the total squared (PERPENDICULAR) distance of each point to the regression line. If this had been the case, my assumption would have been true. However, the two measure of distance never coincide unless there is perfect correlation.

Comment: This is correct. To get a unique solution you effectivel need to minimize the orthodonal distances.